# Python - Communicate with subprocess using stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipe

Lately I was trying to write a simple python code which was supposed to communicate with another process using `stdin`. Here's what I tried so far:

File `start.py`:

```
import sys
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

proc = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "receive.py"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

proc.stdin.write(b"foo\n")
proc.stdin.flush()
print(proc.stdout.readline())
```

File `receive.py`:

```
import sys

while True:
    receive = sys.stdin.readline().decode("utf-8")

    if receive == "END":
        break

    else:
        if receive != "":
            sys.stdout.write(receive + "-" + receive)
            sys.stdout.flush()
```

Unfortunately, when I `python3 start.py` as a result I get `b''`. How should I answer to the prompt of another process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub-process ends early. You can check it by printing `stderr` of the sub-process.

```
# after proc.stdin.flush()
print(proc.stderr.read())
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "receive.py", line 4, in <module>
    receive = sys.stdin.readline().decode()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

### The reason why the sub-process ends early

`sys.stdin.readline()` returns a string (not a byte string); Trying to call `decode` against a string cause AttributeError in Python 3.x.

To fix the issue, remove `decode(..)` call in `receive.py`:

```
receive = sys.stdin.readline()  # without decode.
```

---

And, to make `start.py` complete, send `END`, and close `stdin` of sub-process; let sub-process finish gracefully.

```
proc.stdin.write(b"foo\n")
proc.stdin.flush()
print(proc.stdout.readline())
proc.stdin.write(b'END')  # <---
proc.stdin.close()        # <---
# proc.wait()
```

Comment: He'll also need to `rstrip()` the `receive` line if he wants to compare it with `END` as it will come with an `\n` at the end.

Comment: @zwer, OP didn't send `END` at all; and I send `END` (without newline) in the answer.

Comment: `END` should end with an `\n` in order to be picked up by the `sys.stdin.readline()` in `receive.py` in the first place. Just suggesting improvements to your answer instead of writing mine, don't shoot the messenger :)

Comment: @zwer, `proc.stdin.close()` will make sure `sys.stdin.readline()` in the sub-process to return. I will not bother to length the answer. :) It's already messed with my poor English. Thank you for your feedback anyway. I didn't mean to shoot somebody :P

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. When I run `start.py` I get error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 12, in <module>
    proc.stdin.close()        # <---
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`

Comment: @AdamPisula, Make sure chaging `receive.py` also. See https://asciinema.org/a/chpcnswwhev7i13xt5w2r5imw